# Db engine support for M2 other than mysql

Tags: magento2, database

**TL;DR:** Why does M2 not support other db types other than mysql?

**Long version:**

This is not a philosophical question or an opinion based one. I'm asking why does M2 not support other db engine from the technical point of view.

What are the specific pieces of code that are only mysql compatible and that would require too much work to make it db agnostic?

I don't need a full list, but a few examples like "In this class / file *insert class name and/or github link* this piece of code is used *insert code here* that only works on mysql".

Comment: maybe in favor of `EE` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mysql supports "insert on duplicate key update" from begining. postgres added that feature at 9.5 version. oracle does not support it.

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong and superficial but I think one of the reasons may be the fact that some DBMS have limits on column names length. Oracle is one of that, limiting approx to ~30 chars.

That said, when it comes to indexing EAV entities, we lose control over the length of the generated column name.

This can be a possible source of problems but I never investigated deeply.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't think this is it, but this explains another puzzle I have. There is this constant: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Eav/Model//Entity/Attribute.php#L27 with the value of 30. I guess someone tried to make it compatible with Oracle and dropped it.